# Fix description for hats reachable via app

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2016

I am starting to get hats which awarded when I use app. But occasionally I get nothing.

As I was explained later I use wrong app. It was SoClient.

I think in hats description should be added name of app I must use to get hats.

Comment: The long description already mentions *vote on seven questions or answers using **the** Android or iOS app*. So it's not sufficient to just use *a* random app. Which app would they mean?

Comment: Though it would be slightly more clear, and not much longer if that were  *the **official** Android or iOS app*.